# Does Amazon Cloudfront Support Node coded in ES6?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, amazon-cloudfront

Does CloudFront support node.js coded in ES6? I have tried looking into Amazon docs but didn't manage to find anything.

Comment: I have to imagine that if they support recent versions of Node, the ES6 features listed [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) ought to work fine.

Comment: I am currently running node v. 5.9.1 on my local machine right now but I have to use the babel module to run ES6 code so I wasn't sure if AWS would support it natively.

Comment: If the latest version of Node doesn't support it, there's no way AWS will. They're using the exact same runtime as everyone else.

Comment: Sweet, thanks a lot @JoeClay. Guess I'll have to stick with ES5 for now haha

Comment: You could always use the Babel CLI to compile your code, and then deploy that to AWS :) Although that said, all the features in the first list on the page I linked should work natively, so if you pick and choose which ES6 features you use, you might be able to get by without!

Comment: oh nice! I just tried it and it works perfectly :) TYSM xD saved me from writing so many lines of code lol

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: @JoeClay *If the latest version of Node doesn't support it, there's no way AWS will. They're using the exact same runtime as everyone else.* Huh? **What does that even mean?** In no meaningful sense whatsoever is CloudFront using a Node runtime.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I assumed they meant AWS in general, rather than Cloudfront in particular - though I'll admit, I'm not that familiar with those services. Judging from his replies, I think that's what he meant. The point remains the same though - if the features he's trying to use aren't supported on the latest release of Node, then it's not going to magically start working once he puts the code on someone else's server.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right @JoeClay.  Re-reading my comment, it comes off a little harsh, and I apologize for that.  It was the question itself that made me ask "wait, what?"  Sort of like, "can I use my telephone to speak both French *and* Italian?"  Yes, you can.  It seems like we should post an answer to the effect that CloudFront is back-end agnostic, as long as your back-end speaks valid HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Just Reposting the answer from the comments above to make it slightly clearer for viewers :)

You could always use the Babel CLI to compile your code, and then deploy that to AWS :) Although that said, all the features in the first list on the page I linked should work natively, so if you pick and choose which ES6 features you use, you might be able to get by without! – Joe Clay